# How to sum a value of a column filtering by the highest value of another column?

Tags: sql

Having a table with this values:

```
Document  | Version | Value
----------|---------|-----------
1900001   |    1    |   100
1900001   |    2    |    50
1900001   |    3    |    25
1900002   |    1    |    45
1900002   |    2    |    10
```

How can i get the sum only of the highest version of each document?

Expected value:

35

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple method uses a correlated subquery:

```
select sum(value)
from t
where t.version = (select max(t2.version)
                   from t t2
                   where t2.document = t.document
                  );
```